# How to show text besides input tags in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show the text next to radio buttons in another element when the buttons are clicked.

My HTML:

```
<p>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="General">
I need a simple template
</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="General">
I need a simple template based
</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="General">
I need a simple template based type
</p>
```

I want to show the result in an element with the class `display`, so something like:

```
$('.display').val();
```

I tried this:

```
$('.display').val($('input[type=radio]:checked').closest('p').html());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "besides"? *"I have a class to show the output"* Huh?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The texts used after the input tags.

Comment: Sorry for my knowledge....  I got the texts associated the input tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that what you want to do is put the text associated with the selected radio button in the `.display` element. If so, with your current HTML, you can use `.text` on the parent element to get the text, and then probably `.text` (not `.val`) on the `.display` element to show it (it would be `.val` if `.display` were a form field):

```js
$("input[name=General]").on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).closest('p').text();
  $(".display").text(text);
});
```

```html
<p>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="General">
I need a simple template
</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="General">
I need a simple template based
</p>
<p>
<input type="radio" value="3" name="General">
I need a simple template based type
</p>
<p class="display"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**But**, it's better to use `label` elements so the user can click on the words as well as the actual radio button:

```js
$("input[name=General]").on("click", function() {
  var text = $(this).closest('label').text();
  $(".display").text(text);
});
```

```html
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="General">
    I need a simple template
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="General">
    I need a simple template based
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="General">
    I need a simple template based type
  </label>
</p>
<p class="display"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I would be better if you use `change` instead of `click`

Comment: @ozil: Either is fine. Both are fired by browsers, even if you use the keyboard. The problem with `change` is that some browsers don't fire it until focus leaves the element (er....or so I seem to recall, haven't tried it in a long time).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder     `$('.history').html("<p>" + $('input[type=radio]:checked').closest('p').text() + "</p><br/>");`    I use this code to show all the checked texts, but it shows all the data as a string, i want to show them in separate line.

Comment: history class is in div tags

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of the problem with getting the associated text of check Box in separate Line when the name is same.

HTML Code-

```
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="5" type="checkbox"> I do not need any unique graphics designed (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="6" type="checkbox"> I will supply images (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="7" type="checkbox"> I have a template but it needs minor customization (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="8" type="checkbox"> I need a template customized (0 Hours)</p>
<p><input name="SiteLayoutDesign" value="9" type="checkbox"> I would like a custom design created for my site (0 Hours)</p>
```

jQuery Code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(){
        var $check = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
        $check.each(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            var did = $('input[type=checkbox][value='+id+']:checked').closest('p').text();

        });
    });
});
```

The did variable store the associated text with respect to value of that checkBox.